# How to remove remove multiple different extensions from a word list in GNU make?

Tags: makefile

I have a list of filenames:

```
FILES := a.b c.d e.f
```

and I want to remove the extensions (suffixes) of all words to obtain:

```
a c e
```

what is the best way to do that?

The best I could come up with was "cheating" with shell:

```
$(shell for f in $(INS_NODIR); do echo -n "$${f%.*} "; done )
```

but I am surprised there was not a more "built-in" way of doing this only with make built-in functions.

thing I tried:

- `patsubst`. It seems that it can only have one single wildcard, others being treated literally, and I'd like to do something like `%.%, %`
- looking for a `notsufix` function.

  I was surprised that this does not exist, since the `dir` function has `notdir` counterpart, but the `suffix` function that exactly extracts extensions does not have a `notsuffix` counterpart

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simple, just:

```
NAMES = $(basename $(FILES))
```

See the GNU make manual section on [Functions for File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)

Comment: tnx... I had seen that page, skimmed over all functions, but I supposed `basename` would do the same as the POSIX utility (leave whatever comes after the last `/`) and which is the most common definition idea that comes to mind for basename today